# My App's APK and Flash

Tags: android, flash

Is it possible to include the installer of Flash inside my Application's APK? So that if my application will be installed, flash will automatically be installed too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you can check for Flash Player when your app starts and direct the user to download it but be aware that Flash may not be available for the device being used.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to edit your answer whenever an updated solution is available.